# Получение информации из потоков

Tags: python

Вопрос, собственно, состоит в том, как получить информацию из потока. Есть консольная программа, выполняющая копирование файлов по сети. В силу потребностей, она была доработана и задачи запускаются в потоках. Вот, собственно, и требуется получить информацию о статусе выполнения программы в потоке. Может кто делал что подобное или работал с потоками?

Answer (score 1):

Для обмена информацией между потоками можно использовать очереди. Вот [документация](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) к ним. В конце есть пример для работы с потоками. [Вот](http://progbook.net/python/8416-programmirovanie-na-python-tom-ii.html) отличная книга по программированию на Python. В частности там есть много примеров по многопоточности.Либо книга Бизли Подробный справочник по Python гл. 20. Та же документация только на русском в виде книги.

Comment: А есть хорошие примеры на русском? Я читал документацию, но не могу разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скопировать сетевые файлы из списка `filenames` по 20 файлов одновременно, можно использовать ThreadPool и докладывать о текущем прогрессе в основном потоке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def copy_file_over_network(filename):
    try: 
        # copy file here
        ...     
    except Exception as e: # error
       return filename, str(e)
    else: # success
       return filename, None

pool = ThreadPool(20) # copy 20 files at a time
total = float(len(filenames))
it = pool.imap_unordered(copy_file_over_network, filenames)
for i, (filename, error) in enumerate(it, start=1):
    if error is None:
       print(u"Скопировал {:%} {}".format(i/total, filename))
    else:
       print(u"Не смог скопировать {:!r}: {}".format(filename, error))
```

Питон отпускает GIL во время операций по вводу/выводу т.е., файлы могут действительно копироваться параллельно: производительность скорее всего ограничивается только скоростью диска или пропускной способностью (или задержкой) сети.

Answer (score 0):

В [статье](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-python_part_9/) пишут:

```
Питоновская реализация многопоточности ограниченная. Интерпретатор питона использует внутренний глобальный блокировщик (GIL), который позволяет выполняться только одному потоку. Это сводит на нет преимущества многоядерной архитектуры процессоров. Для многопоточных приложений, которые работают в основном на дисковые операции чтения/записи, это не имеет особого значения, а для приложений, которые делят процессорное время между потоками, это является серьезным ограничением.
```

Вам все еще хочется использовать потоки?

Comment: Правильно, используйте multiprocessing.

Comment: @avp, так ведь ТС как раз и использует дисковые операции. Так что для него выгода явно есть.

К тому же - разве до некоторого времени (или до сих пор?) многозадачность не была липовой?

"Липовая" - т.к. в единицу времени выполнялся только один процесс, остальные ждали когда очередь до них дойдет.

Насколько понял питон предоставляет аналогичный функционал.

Comment: @avp, GIL - бяка и свинья гадостная. Самая мерзкая вещь в питоне (и, пожалуй, единственная). Но если цель создания потоков - обеспечение независимости выполняемого кода, а не распределенные вычисления, то большой проблемы это не составляет.

Comment: @mikillskegg, и обычных-то posix threads лучше избегать, а уж в скриптовой реализации... 

IMHO лучше разделить работу на независимые **процессы** (fork()) и обмениваться результатами по пайпу.

Comment: @avp, это все зависит от задачи.

Comment: Питон отпускает GIL во время дисковых (сетевых) операций т.е., для случая описанного в вопросе можно с выгодой использовать потоки.